# Python : How to pause and resume threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Tornado server with websockets:

```
class SockHandler(SockJSConnection):

    def on_open(self, request):
        clients.add(self)


    def on_message(self, message):

        if (message == 'start'):
            self.send({'message' : start_msg})

            thr = threading.Thread(target=func_with_loop, args=(self.on_result,)).start()

        if (message == 'next'):
            # resume 'thr'


    def on_result(self, response):
        self.send(response)
        # pause 'thr'

    def on_error(self, e):
        print(e)

    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self)
        self.close()
```

On the UI i have 'start' and 'next' buttons that send these messages through the socket connection.

I'm creating a thread at 'start' which triggers a function which runs a finite loop and calls the callback `self.on_result` in each loop.

This works perfectly fine right now. But what I need to do is to execute commands at the two comments to pause and resume the thread.

How should I achieve this ?
Thanks